# Mongoengine raw find_and_modify query gives "Must either update or remove" exception

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using Django + mongoengine
I want to update the books (embedded document) count in my Bookscollection document. I want the update query to return the full object. Therefore I am using the 'find_and_modify'. But even if I use update or remove fields. I still get an error that 'Must either update or remove'.
Here is my code snippet -

```
for book_id in book_list:
        book_col = BookCollection._get_collection().find_and_modify({
                        'query': {'coll_id':book_coll_id,'book.book_id':book_id},
                        'update':{'$inc':
                             {'book.$.quantity' : 1}
                         },
                        'new':True
        })
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find_and_modify`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.9/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify) takes a keywords arguments that is why you are getting that error message.

```
for book_id in book_list:
    book_col = BookCollection._get_collection().find_and_modify({
                        query={'coll_id':book_coll_id,'book.book_id': book_id},
                        update={'$inc': {'book.$.quantity' : 1}},
                        new=True
                })
```

Also you should know that `find_and_modify` is deprecated in pymongo3.0 you should use the [`find_one_and_update`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) if your diver is [pymongo 2.9](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.9/api/pymongo/collection.html) or newer.

Answer (score 2):

```
BookCollection._get_collection().find_and_modify(
                    query={'coll_id':book_coll_id,'book.book_id': book_id},
                    update={'$inc': {'book.$.quantity' : 1}},
                    new=True
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here after pymongo 3.0, you need to use `.find_one_and_update` instead of `find_and_modify` since it is deprecated.

example:

```
book_col = BookCollection._get_collection().find_one_and_update(
                filter={'coll_id':book_coll_id,'book.book_id': book_id},
                update={'$inc': {'book.$.quantity' : 1}},
                new=True
        )
```